# Removing punctuation in Python function

Tags: python

I saw someone use the below code to remove punctuation, and I'm trying to wrap my head around what each line means.

```
def remove_punct(text):
  text  = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
  text = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', text)
  return text
```

I get that the first line is defining a function called "remove_punct", but what does the empty double quotation marks in the second line mean?

Comment: This function is doing more than removing punctuation, it also strips off all digits at some point.  You should include some sample inputs/outputs, and also tell us what _your_ requirement is (it may not agree with the intention of the function).

Comment: `"".join(list)` joins elements from list using empty string - so list of chars will give word. Try `print("".join(['a', 'b','c']))` and `print("|".join(['a', 'b','c']))`

Answer (score 1):

```
string.punctuation
```

Using variable `punctuation` from package `string`. Before using need to import package using line `import string` in the beginning of file.

`string.punctuation` contains all punctuation characters to not have to define them each time manually. It is equal to

```
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

So,

```
[char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
```

For each character in text append this character to a list, if this character is not in string.punctuation, returning list.

```
"".join(some_list)
```

join all elements of a list to a string with "" (empty) delimiter. Means that it will just join all elems. For example, `"=".join([1, 2, 3])` will produce `'1=2=3'`, when `"".join([1, 2, 3])` produces `'123'`

So that line:

```
text = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
```

Just removes all punctuation characters from string and then constructs new string, saving to `text` variable

the second line of function:

```
text = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', text)
```

Substitutes all matches of [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `[0-9]+` to empty string `''`. This means all digits will be deleted from string because `[0-9]+` means "from one to infinite count of characters from 0 to 9 in a row" on regexp language

Last line just returns `text` from function to place where function was called.

```
return text
```